# How to remove a node from BigCouch cluster?

Tags: couchdb, cluster-computing, bigcouch

I created BigCouch cluster with 4 nodes, simply by sending PUT to nodes databases:

```
curl -X PUT http://bigcouch-a.example.com:5986/nodes/bigcouch@bigcouch-a.example.com -d {}
curl -X PUT http://bigcouch-a.example.com:5986/nodes/bigcouch@bigcouch-b.example.com -d {}
curl -X PUT http://bigcouch-a.example.com:5986/nodes/bigcouch@bigcouch-c.example.com -d {}
curl -X PUT http://bigcouch-a.example.com:5986/nodes/bigcouch@bigcouch-d.example.com -d {}
```

All nodes were registered properly, sending GET to membership returns all 4 nodes:

```
{"all_nodes":[
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-a.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-b.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-c.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-d.example.com"]
 "cluster_nodes":[
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-a.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-b.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-c.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-d.example.com"]
}
```

**The question is: how to remove a node?**

I tried to send DELETE to the nodes database

```
curl -X DELETE http://bigcouch-a.example.com:5986/nodes/bigcouch@bigcouch-d.example.com
```

but i got an error:

```
{"error":"conflict", "reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

Once I simply stopped node d then my membership returned:

```
{"all_nodes":[
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-a.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-b.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-c.example.com"]
 "cluster_nodes":[
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-a.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-b.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-c.example.com",
    "bigcouch@bigcouch-d.example.com"]
}
```

So node `d` disappeared from `"all_nodes"` but still exists as a `"cluster_nodes` member.

I cannot create any new database at this state. Each time I receive a message:

```
could not load validation funs {function_clause,
    [{lists, flatmap,
    [#Fun<couch_db.36.90395586>,
    {nodedown, <<"progress not possible">>}]},
    {couch_db, '-load_validation_funs/1-fun-1-', 1}]}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes db is a couchdb database so you need to pass the current revision to update or delete a document.

See my previous answer on how to move shards: [moving a shard from one bigcouch server to another (for balancing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676972/moving-a-shard-from-one-bigcouch-server-to-another-for-balancing)